# Angular- $uibModalInstance.close() does not close the modal (Weird)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a modal where I take user input. The overall logic of the code is as follows.

User clicks on 'Add' button, a modal pops up asking to enter the input. User enters and clicks okay.

At the controller side, here is the code.

```
$scope.ok = function() {

   if (entered_value == 'disk' {
      //perform some actions
      $uibModalInstance.close(); //this closes the modal
   }

   else {
      // perform some actions
      $uibModalInstance.close();
   }
}
```

This works fine in normal condition. i.e. if user enters disk, first part executes.. if user enters anything else, second part executes.

Please note, I have used  `$uibModalInstance.close()` for the if and else statements. This will just close the modal whenever user enters a value and presses okay.

Problem occurs when I keep clicking okay and enter user value. 
For e.g. 
First click on 'Add', user enters 'data' as input, modal closes.
Second click again on 'Add', user enters 'asa' as input, modal does not close. Because  `$uibModalInstance.close()` was already executed in first part.

How to ensure the modal closes each time in such cases. Hope I was able to convey the problem I am facing properly. Any inputs is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting something like this:

```
$scope.modalInst = $uibModalInstance;
$scope.ok = function() {

if (entered_value == 'disk' {
   //perform some actions
   $scope.modalInst.close(); //this closes the modal
}

else {
   // perform some actions
   $scope.modalInst.close();

}

}
```

This will make it available on the current scope.